# how to send an iq using satanza.js in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmpp, stanza, stanza.io

I'm trying to send this stanza:

```html
<iq to="bmp-develop.phoenix.mahsan.net" type="get" id="lkbxdjn">
  <query xmlns="urn:xmpp:staff:0" type="all" />
</iq>
```

I used the sendIQ method but it sends an empty iq stanza:

```html
<iq to="bmp-develop.phoenix.mahsan.net" type="get" id="lkbxdjn"/>
```

What should i do? I tried this code:

```js
client.sendIQ({
    to: "bmp-develop.phoenix.mahsan.net",
    type: "get",
    id: "lkbxdjn",
    children: [`<query xmlns="urn:xmpp:staff:0" type="all" />`]
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((er) => console.log(er));
```

Comment: Have you checked the for errors in your code? There's an obvious syntax error...